# asynchronous load ImagePart data error

Tags: asynchronous, openxml, docx

I use DocumentFormat.OpenXml for generating docx. I try to load small png images (20-50 kb) to my docx asynchronously from WebClient. And I have different result for one code:

- No problem
- NullReferenceException
- FileFormatException
- ObjectDisposedException
- InvalidOperationException

This code demonstrates my problem:

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(outputStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                var mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
                var tasks = Directory.GetFiles("images").Select(async it =>
                    await AddImagePart(it, mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png)).ConfigureAwait(false));
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes("output.docx", outputStream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private static async Task AddImagePart(string path, ImagePart imagePart)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var image = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(path).ConfigureAwait(false);
            imagePart.FeedData(new MemoryStream(image));
        }
    }
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" version="2.7.2" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="System.IO.Packaging" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

There are described on [git](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) problem with large files and .net less then 4.6. But I use small files and .net4.6.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read [this post](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/12/20/pitfalls-of-async-await/) about async\await mistakes.

Try to make `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Link is broken. I had edited my question with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Problem had not solved.